# Ruby on Rails: rb_class_superclass not located in msvcrt-ruby191.dll (ruby-prof error?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundler, rake-task, ruby-prof

So, long story short, I had o format and reinstall my OS hence all my dev utilities.
git env sorted.
DevKit was fine.
Sphinx/mysql fine.
Bundle installed perfectly.
Everything is gravy until I go to rake db:create and build my database.

Environment:
OS: Win7 64-bit
Ruby192
gem -v 1.8.24
rails 3.1.3

Now the problem, when I rake anything I get a pop-up window

```
ruby.exe - Entry Point Not Found

The procedure entry point rb_class_superclass could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt-ruby191.dll
```

I've tried clean installing ruby, clearing the gems and reinstalling. Stuck on what to do next.

trace output:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- ruby/prof
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `rescue in block in require'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
E:/Documents/Websites/rails-app /trunk/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
E:/Documents/Websites/rails-app/trunk/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

I've seen similar issues raised but for different lines in the dll and relating to sqlite3. I'm not using sqlite3 at all though. I'm on mysql with the mysql2 connector.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured this out.

In the gemfile I replaced:

```
gem "ruby-prof"
```

with:

```
gem "ruby-prof", "0.10.8"
```

and all of a sudden I was rolling onto the next issue, which was specifying my rake version. I think both issues are related to an incompatability between the gems and my rubygems verson (I'm guessing??). This is the only difference I could see between my laptop environment, my desktop environment and my production server.

Either way. Sorted!